# order by word in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

For E.g

I have word "John Roshan" i want to arrange this order by first alphbet of  the each word that means the output of the above word should be "Roshan John".

I want to do it with SQL

Please help me its urget.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not clear what you ask. `J` is before `R`.

Comment: Do you mean you have a column storing a name as firstname, lastname but you want to output it as lastname, firstname?

Comment: I hate to ask, but... should John2 be sorted or after John10? :-)

Comment: *It always amazes me that people expect me to spend my time answering questions they won't spend their time asking.*

Comment: We need to consider only 1 character of the each word for e.g if the world is "2000 roshan john" then output should be '2000 john roshan' because '2000' first char 2 is number  & 'john' becasue first character i.e 'J' comes before 'roshan'  'r' in our A TO Z alphabets

Comment: @John, the question is likely to get closed. Should you repost it, please take some effort to provide some *correct* example in- and outputs. It would clear things up. We all know the alphabet but according to your example, `John Roshan` would become `Roshan John`. This contradicts what you now write as a comment. *Answering to comments people make would help to.*

Comment: Please don'r say a quesion is urgent if you can't give enough information for us to answer. And if it's urgent, I assume you've tried already: what did you try?

Comment: @John, if it only needs to consider the **first character**, what happens if you have, for example, "John James Johnson"?

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @S varchar(50)
set @S = 'John Roshan 2000'

;with cte as
(
  select 
    1 as P1,
    charindex(' ', @S+' ', 1) as P2
  union all
  select
    C.P2+1,
    charindex(' ', @S+' ', C.P2+1) as P2
  from cte as C
  where charindex(' ', @S+' ', C.P2+1) > 0
)

select
(
  select substring(@S, P1, P2-P1)+' '
  from cte
  order by substring(@S, P1, P2-P1)
  for xml path(''), type
).value('.', 'varchar(50)')
```

Comment: +1 as this is most likely what OP meant.